# Hi im trying to use a while loop to show range from (4, 49, 2) ex 4 8 12 16 20..but I have to use the while loop. How would I code thise?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, range

```py
x = 4
while x is == or < 49 in range(4, 49, 2):
    print(f'????\t",end'')
```

I am trying to print the following range of numbers with the while loop in a single line

Ex.( 4 8 12 16 20....48)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in one line but in two lines it is:

```python
x = 4
while x < 49: print(x); x += 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of both `while` and `range()` in this question doesn't make much sense.  Plus, the range is specifying an increment of 2, while the desired output increments by 4.  The easier way to get the desired output in one-liner is to use `for` instead.

```
for x in range(4, 49, 4): print(x)
```

If you really want a range with 2 increment, but only print those divisible by 4.

```
for x in [y for y in range(4, 49, 2) if y % 4 == 0]: print(x)
```

If you really want a `while` loop over a range, then loop over an index to the range.

```
vals = range(4, 49, 4)
idx = 0
while idx < len(vals): print(vals[idx]); idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't trying to make all of your code one line, but trying to print all of your output on one line. Your current code is close, but there are a few errors.

Here's a corrected version of the original. Note the lack of `range` here, it's not necessary.

```py
x = step = 4
while x <= 49:
    print(f"{x}\t", end="")
    x += step
print()
```

This far more efficient and easier to read as a for loop.

```py
for x in range(4, 49, 4):
    print(f"{x}\t", end="")
print()
```

Finally, if you **must** use a while loop *and* range, this will work, but the while loop serves no real purpose.

```py
while True:
    for x in range(4, 49, 4):
        print(f"{x}\t", end="")
    break
print()
```

Comment: wow thank you very much. Both examples using the "for" and "while" loops allowed me to see it was simply the operands I was using "==" versus <= 49 and also deifning x as a number within the range I was using. I appreciate everyones help

Comment: @JoshuaChung Don't forget to upvote and accept an answer!

Answer (score -1):

This works for Python 3.9:

```py
while (x:=x+4 if 'x' in locals() else 4) < 49: print('{}\t'.format(x))
```

Comment: whoa,, Im taking an intro to python class and I dont think im in the chapter showing that short of (x:=x+4.lol but thank you I'll keep it in mind. Man this is fun to learn but frustrating as well.